# 「外向的な計算機科学者」の解釈

Tags: 日本語

stackoverflow.comに [What is your best programmer joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke) という質問があります。  
この質問自体はオフトピックですが、その中のジョークについての疑問があります。

質問のなかで以下のジョークが例示されています。

> **Q**: How do you tell an introverted computer scientist from an extroverted computer scientist?  
>   **A**: An extroverted computer scientist looks at *your* shoes when he talks to you.

日本語に訳すとすればこのようになると思います。

> **Q**: 内向的な計算機科学者と外向的な計算機科学者をどうやって見分けるか？  
>   **A**: 外向的な計算機科学者はあなたと話すとき**あなたの**靴を見る.

どうしてこれがジョークとして成立するのでしょうか。

まず、"introverted"、"extroverted"、"looks at your shoes"といった表現に字面以外の特殊な意味があるのかと思ったのですが、調べた限りでは分かりませんでした。"your"が強調されているのも謎です。

知人に尋ねたところ、[How to Shoot Yourself in the Foot in Any Programming Language](http://www.fullduplex.org/humor/2006/10/how-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-in-any-programming-language/)(プログラミング言語で自分の足を撃つ方法)というジョークに関連があるのではないかという話でした。しかし、もしこのジョークを下敷きにしていたとしても、「プログラマー」ではなくわざわざ「計算機科学者」とする必要がない上、内向的か外向的かという対比との関連性も理解できません。「足」でなくて「靴」になっていますし関連させているようには見えません。

自分が思いついた一番妥当な解釈は、（相手の顔を見ずに）靴を見ながら話すのは一般的には内向的な人の特徴なのだが、計算機科学者は比較的外向的な人ですらそうなのだ、というものです。（それだけ計算機科学者は総じて内向的ということ？）

英語は得意とは言えないのでかなり的はずれな考えをしているのかもしれませんが、どのように解釈するのが適当か教えていただきたいです。

Comment: この質問はスタックオーバーフローの範囲から外れているように思えます。良い質問をするためにヘルプセンターの[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)を見てはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: [メタでの話し合い](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1500/30)でオントピックとするかの扱いが決まるまで、保留にします。

Comment: @h2so5 メタに投稿するには信用度が5以上である必要があります。もしご意見があれば、こちらにコメントしていただくか、他の質問・回答の投稿を通して信用度をためてからメタにご参加ください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

その解釈でいいと思います。"your"が強調されているのは、「内向的な計算機科学者は "自分自身の" 靴を見るから」と解釈させるためでしょう。